# In which cases does try-catch catch exceptions?

Tags: scala, exception, try-catch

I've just started learning Scala, so this might be a simple question. I want to use a try-catch block to check if a variable has been declared or not.

I am using a try-catch block and catching the `NoSuchElementException` if the variable doesn't exist.

```
try{
  print(testVariable)
}
catch{
  case e: NoSuchElementException => print("testVariable not found")
}
```

My code is showing an error that `testVariable` does not exist instead of throwing the exception. I then tried multiple other exceptions as well, but Scala's try-catch doesn't seem to be catching any of them (except for the divide by zero exception).

Can someone please guide me on how to use Scala's try-catch block?

Comment: how do you throw the exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Scala (or pretty much any *compiled* programming language really), checking if a variable has been declared or not is the compiler's job, done at compile time. If you try to use a variable that hasn't been declared, the compiler will give an error, and your code won't be able to run.

Exceptions are a way to represent problems at run-time.

There is no overlap between "compile time" and "run-time", so what you are trying to do doesn't make sense. **There just *isn't* an exception for "variable does not exist", and that's why you can't catch it.**

To contrast, take this example:

```
val map = Map('a' -> 1, 'b' -> 2)
map('c') // will throw NoSuchElementException because there is no 'c' in the map
```

In this case, `map.apply('c')` (syntax sugar for `apply` lets you do `map('c')` will throw an exception because that's how Map's apply method is implemented. See [the definition of `Map#apply`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L148) which calls [Map#default](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L243) if the key wasn't in the map; `Map#default` throws a NoSuchElementException.

You could catch that exception with a try/catch, e.g.

```
try {
  map('c')
} catch {
   case e: NoSuchElementException =>
     println("got it!")
}
```